# How to add a static library in CocoaPod project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I am developing a React Native module and its iOS dependency is managed by CocoaPod.

I need to use a library `libXXX.a` in my CocoaPod project.
How do I add it?

Comment: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#static_framework, https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_libraries

Comment: Posted some links above that may help. If you add what your current podspec looks like I may be able to help further.